# window keypress event listener calling function

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Manoeuvre from '../Manoeuvre/Manoeuvre';
import Box from '../Box/Box';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      top: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom : 0,
      left: 0

    }

  }


  doit = () => {
    console.log('this')
  }

  render() {

      window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
        this.doit()
      });



    return (

      <div className="all">
        <Manoeuvre />
        <Box />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Hello, i'am tryin to call the function doit from my eventlistener keypress, but can't figure how to do it, anyone can help? :) I'am stuck on this since a moment now

I got the errot typerror: doit is not  function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` in the context of your anonymous event callback is the callback. You need to either `bind` that callback or use an arrow function.

in addition:

- don't put `window.addEventListener` in your `render` function - this should go in `componentDidMount` (and, in `componentWillUnmount` - *unlisten* (is that a word?).
- why not just `window.addEventListener(this.doit)`? (don't have to worry about binding, here)

Comment: Thanks, it works with the bind on the callback function. Thought i tried with ComponentDidMount, the event listener is working but i can't call the function doit from there

Comment: ... why not - sure you can.

Comment: It just call the function once, but not on the keypress event

Comment: Okey, you were right of course ^^. After some search i got what was wrong, and it works well with the componentDidMount yes, thanks, it helped me a lot :)